# A pretty strange issue caused by HTML DOM's "querySelectorAll" method or "getElementsByTagName" method

Tags: getelementsbytagname, dom, selectors-api

See codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>An HTML5 Document</title>
<p>
<p>
<script>
    var a = [1, 2],
        b = [3, 4],
        c = a.concat(b),
        d, e, f, g;

    console.log(c); // No problem

    d = [document.querySelectorAll('p')[0], document.querySelectorAll('p')[1]];
    e = a.concat(d);
    console.log(e); // No problem

    f = document.querySelectorAll('p'); // f = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    g = a.concat(f);
    console.log(g); // Pretty strange...
</script>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V7gmE

My question is:

`c.length` is `4`. No poblem.
`e.length` is `4`. No poblem.

If I use `f = document.querySelectorAll('p');` or `f = document.getElementsByTagName('p');`, why `g.length` is '3'?

Thank you.

Comment: this is not real production code, right? `d = [document.querySelectorAll('p')[0], document.querySelectorAll('p')[1]];` is doubling your processing for no reason.

Comment: These codes are particularly written for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem, your third array is just `[1, 2, NodeList]`.`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` which in this case contains two elements. In the second example, you specifically take the first and second elements from the NodeList and put them into an array. While NodeLists may seem like arrays, they are not, and when you use the `Array.concat` method on it, the individual elements are not picked out.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList):

> NodeList are used very much like arrays and it would be tempting to use Array.prototype methods on them. This is, however, impossible.

Here is another example that might help get the point across: http://jsfiddle.net/radu/j5gvy/1/

```
var a = [1, 2],
    obj = { 0 : '', 1 : ''},
    b = [obj[0], obj[1]];

c = a.concat(obj);

console.log(c.length); // 3

d = a.concat(b);

console.log(d.length); // 4
```

Just because I define an object that can be accessed like an array does not make it an array.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns an array just like what `[document.querySelectorAll('p')[0], document.querySelectorAll('p')[1]]` does. But I eventually get different result...

Comment: It does not return an array - it returns a `NodeList`. When you do `document.querySelectorAll('p')[0]`, you're taking the first element out of that `NodeList`. It just so happens that they are treated similarly, but you cannot effectively use `Array.concat` or other methods in `Array.prototype` unless you do what you did and first pick out individual results.

Comment: Added an example which might help convince you.

Comment: Thank you. Radu. After I saw your replies and the MDN resource provided by you, I think `querySelectorAll` returns an object, not an array. I feel the worst part of the web may be the HTML DOM.